Elements are hidden inside the scrolled block area
I found a behavior that when we use overflow to scroll content and try to change sub elements' horizontal position, the width of the root block increases, and we can see the changed sub element only if we scroll it to the end of the root block.
So my question is: how to make appear only the vertical scroll to have an opportunity to change the position of the sub elements to make them visible outside the root block?
This following example shows that strong element increases the width of the .block element and it makes appeaser of the horizontal scroll and is hidden inside this element but not offsets outside.
Source code:


.block {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  max-height: 100px;
  background: cyan;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

strong {
  position: absolute;
  left: 300px;
}
<div class="block">
  <div class="item-content">some text some text some text some text some</div>
  <div class="item-content">some text some text some text some text some</div>
  <div class="item-content">some text some text some text some text some</div>
  <div class="item-content">
    <div>some text some text some text some text some</div>
    <strong>some text</strong>
  </div>
</div>




PS: Why would you ever want to position absolute a Strong tag element?

I experimented with positions. For example, if I set fixed, the element places outside the parent element, but offset always calculates from the browser's window

I'm trying to make this behavior with an offset element from the scrollable block in the context menu component. Explaining in simple words, I want to make vertical scroll on menu items and also set submenu items outside the scrollable menu items.

So this example reproduces a similar situation that I try to make in the context menu.

item-content is the first level menu and the last item-content with div and strong elements is the second level menu whick should be outside .block

The best solution I found is using position: fixed. Then you should write the following JS code to control the item's position. This function is actuarial for a context menu item if it has a scrollable sub menu:
import { DomHandler } from 'primevue/utils';

const { getViewport } = DomHandler

export default function nestedPosition(element) {
    if (element) {
        let { left, top, width, height } = element.getBoundingClientRect()

        const parentItem = element.parentElement;
        const parentItemClientRect = parentItem.getBoundingClientRect()

        top = parentItemClientRect.top
        left = parentItemClientRect.width + left

        const viewport = getViewport();

        if (left + width > viewport.width) {
            left = parentItemClientRect.left - width
        }

        if (top + height > viewport.height) {
            top -= height - parentItemClientRect.height
        }


        element.style.top = `${top}px`;
        element.style.left = `${left}px`;
    }
}

And also use CSS as an example of how it could be in a real context menu:
.p-contextmenu .p-submenu-list {
  position: fixed;
  max-height: 300px;
  min-width: 230px;
  max-width: 520px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

